# Add Item ID At The End of a Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a complex MYSQL query which I run from multiple sources of data and that can be ordered depending on the request ( so record id is not much help ).

I want to add a unique ID column at the completion of the data each time the query is run so I can enable pagenation capability of the data.

If I was doing this at the database level I could use `id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT` but this is about doing the addition on the fly every time a query has run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  *, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) rank
FROM YourcomplexQuery, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t;
```

However, you can use the MySQL built in function `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT --
FROM Yourtable
ORDER BY SomeField
LIMIt 0, n;
```

Comment: Thanks... I will look in to this and update if it works ( which I'm sure it will)

Comment: Implemented - tested and working - many thanks for that simple solution.